# Retrieve the order id and the number of days between order date and payment date for all orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

Ans...,

```
select orderid as "ORDERID", abs(pymtdate-Orderdate) as "NOOFDAYS"
from orders
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: hello jarlh i used mysql

Comment: Dale k here is the question the number of days between order date and payment date for all orders

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql server then you need to use `Datediff()`:

```
select orderid as "ORDERID", abs(datediff(day,pymtdate,Orderdate)) as "NOOFDAYS" 
from orders
```